# Vue-router shared component with route params changes to filter results

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to dynamically filter results in a single component with route params, but even in Vue-router's `beforeEnter` guard, it only detects changes when initially entering the component:

```
{
  path: '/ants/:filter',
  name: 'ants.index',
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    next(store.getters['ants/filter'](to.params.filter))
  },
  component: () => import(`@/pages/ants/Index.vue`)
}
```

There are three filters currently. The `to.params.filter` detects the correct filter the first time you enter the component, but after that it doesn't detect route params changes as it is re-using that same component. I would be ok with re-loading the component, though the filter is filtering through state so it should be an efficient data swap. I'm just unclear on how I would detect the route params change. Any other possible solutions are welcome as well! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeRouteUpdate` in-component guard:

```
beforeRouteUpdate: (to, from, next) {
  next(store.getters['ants/filter'](to.params.filter))
}
```

Comment: I was looking at that. Where do you use it? Somewhere before created?

Comment: You add it on the same level as created, methods, data etc.

Comment: @MattLarson It is a property of the component. just like `data` or `created` would be. `Vue-Router` augments the `ComponentOptions` typing to support this. You can [see that addition here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts#L15)

Comment: Ah. Yeah, for some reason it's actually altering my params... I have three filters: my, team, all. Whichever param.filter I use first, it shares that same param for each route change. Though it does log the param change, but inconsistently.

Comment: @MattLarson Can you make a quick example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: @MattLarson Great.

Comment: Scratch that! A combination of both works, which makes sense. `beforeRouteEnter` catches the first param and then `beforeRouteUpdate` catches any/all changes while inside the component is being re-used.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way would be to use this:

Note: Put this code on the same level as `created: { }`, `methods: { }` etc

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // Your code.
  }
}
```

Route guards are better but if you're finding you need to use lots of them and call the same code then this could work instead as it reacts to any route changes.

Comment: `watch` only works once inside the component, so it wouldn't catch the first param. In that case I could use a combination of `created` and `watch`, but `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteUpdate` seem better suited

Comment: Yes, fair point. I normally have a function that gets called on created and also call it on the watch for things like this. Runs the same code on each but as you say the other option works the same.